# Verilog - Getting immediate response from external memory

Tags: verilog, hdl

I'm trying to write a Verilog module which iterates over elements of an external memory in **each cycle**. The problem I'm facing right now, is that changing the address of the memory during the cycle will not cause the input data be changed, in that same cycle.i.e: changing the address will not cause the input data to be changed in one cycle.I'll illustrate the problem with some code:

```
module r(input rst, ..., output reg [MEMORY_ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] addr, input memory_value);

//...
always @(posedge clk) begin
    //...
    for(addr = 0; addr < MEMORY_SIZE; addr = addr+1) begin        
        if (memory_value) //...
        // PROBLEM: changing addr in this loop doesn't cause memory_value to change
    end
end
endmodule
```

---

And here is how I instantiate the module

```
module top;

 reg mem[MEMORY_SIZE-1:0];
    wire [MEMORY_ADD_WIDTH-1:0] addr;
    //...
    r r( rst, ..., addr, mem[addr]);
endmodule
```

I'm using Modelsim to simulate the design. First of all, is this expected behaviour, and if it is what's a common workaround?

Comment: "memory_value" is an input to the "r" module and so "r" module, itself won't change the value of "memory_value". So, what do you mean, by "changing addr in this loop doesn't cause memory_value to change" ?

Comment: @KaranShah as the OP specified that they're talking to memory, they're likely expecting the `memory_value` to change when they provide a new value on `addr`(which isn't happening; see my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` loops in Verilog are used to create several copies of an assignment. The loop is automatically unrolled (which is why it needs constant bounds).

For example

```
always@(posedge clk)
for (i=1; i<4; i=i+1)
    foo[i] <= foo[i-1]*foo[i-1];
```

is equivalent to

```
always@(posedge clk) begin
    foo[1] <= foo[0]*foo[0];
    foo[2] <= foo[1]*foo[1];
    foo[3] <= foo[2]*foo[2];
end
```

So, the code you provided never assigns a value to `addr`, which is likely why you aren't see any change. (In the same way that `i` doesn't appear in the second part of my example)

---

Consider instead splitting these up.:

```
always@(posedge clk)
    addr<=(addr+1)%ADDR_MAX;

always@(*)begin
    if (memory_value) // mem[addr]
    //...
end
```

Comment: That's completely logical. though how would you handle such a case?

Comment: Split your code up. Have a clocked block as a counter for your address, and a combinational block to evaluate the `memory_value`. I'm assuming you only want to perform one check per clock cycle. (I'll edit some code in as an example)

Comment: If you're trying to do multiple memory reads in one cycle, you'd need a memory that supports that (and at which point, you'll probably be best off making a separate module for each memory word you want to process).